# ResultSet to ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, jdbc, serversocket

I want to create an array for each row.

```
while (result.next()) {
                String[] result1 = {
                        "Dog ID: " + result.getLong("dogs.id"),
                        ", Dog name: " + result.getString("dogs.first_name"),
                        ", Owner name: "
                                + result.getString("owners.first_name"),
                        ", Owner phone: " + result.getString("owners.phone") };
                resultList.add(result1);
```

My code write every one row in one array. 
Can i get numbers of columns and put a limit?

```
while (resultset.next()) {              
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= numberOfColumns) {
```

It's because i can't send entire table as a result from server to client.

Comment: *Can i get numbers of columns and put a limit?* what do you mean?

Comment: You can make use of `limit` in your `SQL` query and have a fixed size of the resultset

Comment: i don't need limit in query. I need to write every one row in own array.

Answer (score 1):

You can query by column number `result.getLong(columnIndex)` but it doesn't make sense in your case withing a loop because you have columns of different types (unless complicating the code).

If you want to optimize the traffic from server to client the way to go is querying for just the columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the rows returned, it might be better to put the limiting criteria into the SQL query and only return the rows you want to include.

Comment: OP doesn't ask how to limit the result of rows but of columns, which is odd.

Comment: The OP wants number of columns rather than number of rows

Comment: Yes, but he almost certainly meant rows, because limiting the number of columns is a trivial select statement.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke we don't know for sure. That's why you can leave comments on OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get number of columns in your ResultSet you can use the following piece of code :

```
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(myQuery);
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numOfColumns = metaData .getColumnCount();
```

Comment: well, but how i can write a algorithm that records each line in its own array

Comment: @user2920764 that's not part of your question. Anyway, looks like you're trying to have a single `String[]` by column, right? Then use `List<List<String>>` first to load the data into RAM and then convert this into your `String[][]` accordingly.

Comment: first row -> firstArray   ; secondRow -> secondArray and finally all arrays in ArrayList

Comment: @user2920764 then I don't understand your problem. Your code works as expected. Voting to close as unclear.